# How to do recursion in javascript by taking parameters as input

Tags: javascript, html, recursion

Please spot the mistake in the code. I don't know how to do recursion by removing parameters. When I remove parameters, code begins to work fine.

**Code Snippet**

```js
let number = document.getElementById("inputN").value;

function result2(number) {
  if (number == 1)
    return 0;
  if (number == 2)
    return 1;
  let answer;
  answer = (number - 1) * (result2(number - 1) + result2(number - 2));
  return answer
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Result: " + result2(number);

}
```

```html
<label for="inputN">Enter the value of n:</label>
<input type="number" id="inputN" min="1" step="1" value="1">
<button onclick="result2(number)">Calculate</button>
<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what [debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193) you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Shows no output when I click the button

Comment: you have unreachable code after the `return`

Comment: @TECHNOMATHEMATICALBIOPHYSICI: Since `number` is set when the page loads and never updated, when you click the button you *always* pass the value `1` to the function.  So the function *always* immediately returns.  You probably want to get the value inside the function, *after* the user has had a chance to enter a value.  (Alongside the unreachable code problem identified above.)

Comment: @David What should I exactly do so that the code runs. innerHTML is outside the function

Comment: It's a good idea to separate logic from I/O. Don't bake any `document` work inside of a function that computes something--put that in the caller and use the return value to manipulate the document. Also, give the function a sensible name that describes the action it takes. `result2` means nothing. I always use `{}` in all conditions and autoformat the code so it's clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of significant problems here:

1. The line of code which produces output is *after* a `return` statement, so it can never execute.
2. You define the value of `number` once, and only once, when the page loads.  That value is `1`.  You *always* call the function with `1`, so it *always* immediately returns.

You can correct both of these by separating your concerns into two functions.  One which reads the input value and writes the output value, and which calls the other function which performs the calculation (recursively).  For example:

```js
function getResult() {
  let number = document.getElementById("inputN").value;
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Result: " + recurse(number);
}

function recurse(val) {
  if (val == 1)
    return 0;
  if (val == 2)
    return 1;
  return (val - 1) * (recurse(val - 1) + recurse(val - 2))
}
```

```html
<label for="inputN">Enter the value of n:</label>
<input type="number" id="inputN" min="1" step="1" value="1">
<button onclick="getResult()">Calculate</button>
<p id="result"></p>
```

Note how the `recurse` function *only* performs the calculation and returns the result.  It is not concerned with where the value came from or what is done with the result.

The other function, `getResult`, is what gets invoked by the UI.  That function reads the input value, invokes the calculation, and displays the result.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple issues with the code you've provided.

First off the 'return' statements like below mean nothing else will be executed

```
function result2(number) {
   if (number == 1)
    return 0;
```

Second, you set 'number' once at the page load. Instead we should just retrieve this number each time the function is called and forget about parsing it in.

This means refactoring the below to something like this, with an 'internal calculate' to obtain your return '0' or '1' functionality.

But also, what happens if you don't have a '1' or '0' - we should return a default.  In this case I just made it 0. Full snippet is below, extracting your internal functionality.

```js
function result() {
  let number = Number(document.getElementById("inputN").value);
  let answer;
  answer = (number - 1) * (internalCalculate(number - 1) + internalCalculate(number - 2));
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Result: " + answer.toString();
}

function internalCalculate(number) {
  if (number === 1)
    return 0;
  if (number === 2)
    return 1;
  else
    return 0;
}
```

```html
<label for="inputN">Enter the value of n:</label>
<input type="number" id="inputN" min="1" step="1" value="1">
<button onclick="result()">Calculate</button>
<p id="result"></p>
```